# Date Format not working with Polish hyphens

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have the code:

```
tempDate = exWS.Cells(exRow, myMatchedColumns(2)).value
```

Which takes the date from a cell in a spreadsheet,
I then have the code:

```
dueDate = Format("dd/MM/yyyy", tempDate)
```

Which changes the date from whatever it is to DD/MM/YYYY which is correct.

However, I've ran my program on a Polish system (Whos' regional default is YYYY-MM-DD) when my code runs;

**Temp Date: YYYY-MM-DD**

**Due Date: DD-MM-YYYY**

So the format puts it the right way around but it's not changing the dashes for a slash.

Naturally my SQL needs it in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Can you help format the date better.

Many thanks

Comment: is this VB.NEt or vba?  They are not the same thing

Comment: Vb .NET .. Mistyped the tag

Answer (score 1):

There are several common misconceptions in the question.

First, and perhaps foremost, you should turn on `Option Strict`.  You likely have some implicit conversions going on.

```
tempDate = exWS.Cells(exRow, myMatchedColumns(2)).value
```

I have no idea how `tempDate` is declared, but I am pretty sure excel cell values are object.  So `tempDate` is at best, a date boxed as `Object`.

```
 dueDate = Format("dd/MM/yyyy", tempDate)
```

That does not "format a Date".  It **converts** a `DateTime` to string in that format.

### Dates do not have a Format

Net `DateTime` types do not have a format.  You cannot apply a format.  There is no *need* to format a Date.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.
>   ...
>   For example, a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date,
>   Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

A `DateTime` is just a Big Number. A *value*.  Today's Date is 635894496000000000L and `DateTime.Now` is 635894883340193705L.

Displaying those values would not make sense even to Eric Lippert<sup>1</sup>, so the `DateTime` type includes code to 'express it as the date and time of day'.  It is even aware of the local culture so that a single date will display differently in Poland vs UK vs Italy with no code or help from us.  Example:

```
Dim myDT = DateTime.Now

Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString("d-M-yyyy"))
' use culture default:  
Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString(New CultureInfo("pl-PL")))
Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString(New CultureInfo("fr-FR")))
```

> 2016-01-27
>   01/27/2016
>   27-1-2016
>   27/01/2016 11:27:13
>   2016-01-27 11:27:13

It is the same exact date and same exact value but displays in any format I want, in any culture I want.

---

#### `Polish hyphens`

As mentioned, `Format()` returns a string, not a date.  But the output is correct because the Polish culture *does not use the slash*:

```
Dim cult = New CultureInfo("pl-PL")
Dim polishDTDisplayFormat = cult.DateTimeFormat
Console.WriteLine(polishDTDisplayFormat.DateSeparator)
' prints '-'
```

Unlike some cultures such as the US or UK which can use either, the slash is not defined for Polish.  `Format` substitutes the legal Date Separator defined for the culture for the illegal character specified.  `DateTime` will do the same:

```
' try to override because I think I know better:
Console.WriteLine(myDT.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", New CultureInfo("pl-PL")))
```

> 2016-01-27

This is a Good Thing!  It prevents us from having to get a culture's DateSeperator and concoct a format string in code.  The powerful `DateTime` type also includes methods such as `ToShortDateString()` to easily display a date in a legal, local order ("M/d/yyyy" vs "yyyy-M-d").

Use this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WImdZ7) to examine all the legal formats for a culture.

---

#### `Naturally my SQL needs it in the format dd/mm/yyyy`

Sorry, but it does not.

Using the (MySql?) NET DB provider objects, and a *column defined as `DateTime`*, you simply need to save your NET `DateTime` variable to the database:

```
 Using dbcon = New MySqlConnection(connstr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbcon)
            dbcon.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDT
            rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
  End Using
```

The same is true for `OleDB`/Access and SQL Server.  They all know what to do.      The NET DB provider objects would be pretty useless they were unable use a NET `DateTime` type for the underlying database.

**Red Herrings**
Access includes a "Format" property for Date columns.  This does not specify the save format, but how you want Access to display it to you in the IDE and the users.  If you wizard up a vba form and map that column to a control, it uses that format for the display.

**In all cases, a format is how the date is displayed (output) not stored.**

Similarly, MySql mentions a required "yyyy-MM-dd" format.  A *careful* reading of the documentation reveals they are talking about date data as text. For instance, the format to use when using the CLI or even Workbench UI.   The result is that this *does* work:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

...but is not needed.  As before this *converts* a `DateTime` **to** a **string** (hence the clever name) which contains date data.  The DB provider objects are going to have to parse it back to a date in order to get the actual *value*.

It can *seem* like it is a required date format because other formats may fail. But this is because you chose to convert a date to text.  This will work fine:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDT
```

#### Summary

- Use `DateTime` variables for date data
- Store date date to date fields in your database
- Use `.ToString(...)` to specify how to display a date to the user
- Turn on `Option Strict` to prevent accidental type conversions
- **Dates do not have an intrinsic format**

---

<sup>1</sup> *probably*